# onPressImage in PhotoGrid returns Proxy object instead of image URI

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, photo-gallery

- I'm using this photo grid: https://reactnativeexample.com/react-native-photo-grid/
- I pass the array with S3 URI's to the component:

[image: example of array with s3 URI's]

- The component displays the images correctly.
- The problem is when I click an image. I try to console.log() the uri of the clicked image, but instead of the s3 uri, I get the Proxy object:

[image: Proxy object returned on image click]

- My code (I had a problem with code snippet so uploaded an image):

[image]

- ComponentDidMount is where I setState with URI's array (after API call to S3 bucket).

Any idea on how can I get the clicked image s3 URI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue was answered in the package github. It just needed a second parameter, like this:

```
<PhotoGrid
   onPressImage={(eventObj, uri) => console.log("image uri", uri)}
/>
```

Cheers!